# My site will only scroll a few hundred pixels down the screen before it freezes on an iPad

Tags: iphone, responsive-design, ipad-2

The question is simple I've tried several different techniques like re-ordering scripts being called in the DOM, removed 100% height from the body and html element in my css; but none of it worked.

My site won't scroll down the page on iPhone or iPad and I can't seem to figure out why. It will scroll a few hundred pixels down the page and then freezes.

I've run an audit in chrome and tightened up as much as I could but, i've checked the timeline but don't see any resources hogging the bandwidth that might cause the page to just freeze like this.

Here is the public facing link (sandbox) I have going on.
https://cloud.spinsys.com/sky/marketing-v3/index.html

Obviously to reproduce the error you'll have to view on an iPad or iPhone or any tablet that you might try it on to see if it works on those.

Has anyone encountered an issue with their site not scrolling on an iPad or iPhone?

It is a responsive site and it's of major importance that I get this fixed.

Any advice, help, suggestions would be most helpful, thanks to the S.O. community upfront.

Comment: Why did this get down-voted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the skrollr.js library. I have removed it and the page scrolls fine on iPad and iPhone.